# How to find the position of the first blank in a string

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have an array of names and I need to find the position of the blank and put anything that comes before it into fname and put everything that comes after the blank into lname. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing and I got help from my teacher and she gave me the 3 lines of code that come after posit_of_blank, fname and lname and said that all I had to do was figure out what goes in place of the ... and I haven't got a clue.

```
using namespace std;
#include "PersonNameFileCreator.h"
#include "PersonName.h"

int main()
{
  string arr_names[] = {"Adam Burke", "Madeline Kramer", "Scott Gardner", 
                        "Tonya Lopez", "Christoper Hamilton", 
                        "Andrew Mitchell", "Lori Smith" };

  PersonNameFileCreator fil_names("names.txt);
  
  for (auto one_name : arr_names)
  {
    int posit_of_blank = ?
    string fname = ?
    string lname = ?
    PersonName onePerson(fname, lname);
    fil_names.write_to_file(onePerson);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific here. What do you mean find the position of the blank? Like a space? or any whitespace? 

Also, show us some examples of what you've tried. This is homework, after all.

Comment: Wait is the picture not there? I created this account today and attached the pic to my post. maybe it didnt go through? Lemme try to attach it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUFBs.png

Comment: Instead of adding a photo to the post, you should add the code to the question. you can do this by using 3 tick mark ``` to open the code and three tick mark ```` to close it.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the `std::string` documentation, it will have what you need.

Given a string `std::string name = "Justin Jones"` you can find the space using the `std::string::find()` or the `std::string::find_first_of()` function. From the example above, you can find the space with `unsigned int spacePosition = name.find(" ");`. This will return the position of the space and then you can use the `std::string::substr` function to split it where you need it.

Here is a link to the find function: https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Here is a link to the substr function: https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Ok so I got the number of where the blank is but when I type in "std::string::substr" it gives me the error that is pictured https://imgur.com/a/xLb2q7V .So I can find the dividing space between the two names and I know that I have to define fname to be the string from position 0 to position of the space and lname to be from the space to the end of the string but im not sure how to do that

Comment: You don't type in exactly ```std::string::substr```. Look at the examples found here:https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/ And read the documentation. Don't just copy and paste my answers.

Comment: @Justin Also, please don't use pictures, type it out.